# Sending json to server using HttpURLConnection, data becomes key rather than value

Tags: php, android, slim

In my app, I tried to send `JSON` data using `HttpUrlConnection`:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(httpConnection.getOutputStream());

// This write the data to server
Log.d("MyDebugMsg", json.toString());
out.write(json.toString());
out.flush();
out.close();
```

And this is how the `JSON` string looks like:

```
{"name":"The Dark Knight","rating":"9"}
```

But when I received from the server, it becomes the key of an Array element whose value is null.

```
Array
(
[{"name":"The_Dark_Knight","rating":"9"}] => 
)
```

I'm new to `PHP` and `Slim`, my `Php` code looks like:

```
$app->post(
    '/add',
    function($request, $response, $args) {
        // $data = $request->getParsedBody();
        // addMovieToDB($data);

        $json = $request->getParsedBody();
        print_r($json);
    }
);
```

Why the data I write to server becomes key rather than value? I fetched out the data from key in this way:

```
$array = $request->getParsedBody();
$data = json_decode(key($array));
```

But I still feel I'm wrong because I'm reading from the key rather than value. Is there any misunderstanding or mistake leads me to this weird situation? Thank you.

Comment: You didn't include a Content-Type header in your HTTP Call... Add Content-Header application/json and retry

Comment: For @geggleto's comment, something like this: `httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");`

Comment: Sorry I'm not a java guy :) just a maintainer of Slim

Comment: No problem, we are here to help each other ;) @geggleto

Comment: OP: if it's not being parsed in getParsedBody then the content-type is wrong in your request.

Comment: @geggleto Thank you, It works!!! By the way, any suggestion to learn PHP and Slim? W3schools is faaaaaar away from enough. And I find myself lack the necessary background knowledge to understand Slim User Guide smoothly. I used to do C++ and Java

Comment: @FirstOne Thank you sooooo much. By the way, any suggestion to learn PHP and Slim? W3schools is faaaaaar away from enough.

Comment: For the learning part, I don't know of any specific tutorial or anything, but some people find it easier to learn with videos... Nonetheless, practice! Try to do stuff out and face problems. When you try to solve them, that's when you learn...

Comment: @FirstOne I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @geggleto:

> if it's not being parsed in getParsedBody then the content-type is
>   wrong in your request.

---

You can **fix** it by sending the correct header:

```
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
```